# How to get data using relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Please I want to make link using id (Semesters)

**this how is my DB :**

- `Courses: id , title , pdf_file , extension , description , matieres_id and timetables`
- `Matieres: id , matiere , semester_id and timetables`
- `Semesters: id , semester, matieres_id and timetables`

**route/web.php**

```php
Route::get('/lms/semestre', 'HomeController@semestres');
Route::get('/lms/', 'HomeController@lms');
Route::get('/lms/matieres/{id}', 'HomeController@matieres');
Route::get('/lms/course/{id}', 'HomeController@course');
Route::get('/lms/courses', 'HomeController@courses');
```

**Course.php (model)**

```php
class Course extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $fillable = ['id'];

    public function matiere()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Matiere::class);
    }
}
```

**Matiere.php (Model)**

```php
class Matiere extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'matieres';
    protected $fillable = ['id'];
    public function semestre()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Semestre::class);
    }
}
```

**Semestre.php (Model)**

```php
class Semestre extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'semestres';
    protected $fillable = ['id'];
    public function matiere()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Matiere::class);
    }
}
```

My issue is how to make url `/lms/courses/{semester_id}` and display a page where is courses list using `course->matiere_id->semesters`.
It's very complicated for me and I don't want to create column `semester_id` in course table.

Comment: Did you try anything in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.
Note: Make sure `CourseDB` is created first before `SemesterDB`

database:

course_db:

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
    });
```

semester_db:

```
Schema::create('semesters', function (Blueprint $table) {
...
$table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
...

$table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
})
```

Model:

course_model:

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function semester() {
return $this->hasOne(Semester::class);
}
```

semester_mode:

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function course() {
return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

controller:

```
App\Course;

public function index() {
$courses = Course::all();
dd($courses->semester);
}
```